# Find multiple elements that are equal to a condition in array?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a new to SwiftUI, so I apologise if this a dumb question but I came upon a problem that I cant find a solution to.

I am searching something similar to this code below, but instead of finding the first element I would like to retrieve all elements that have the status == 0.

```
if let new = array.first(where: {$0.status == 0}) {
   // do something with foo
} else {
   // item could not be found
}
```

Comment: use `.filter` then you can filter out the items that don't match. BTW this has nothing to do with SwiftUI, SwiftUI is only the UI parts, what the user sees/interacts with.

Comment: take a look at this link. https://www.donnywals.com/how-to-filter-an-array-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift collections have a `filter` method which allows you to select all elements that match a given condition. You already have a matching condition, so to adapt your example text you'd write:

```swift
let newItems = array.filter { $0.status == 0 }
```